# avoiding mixed iteration and reading error in Python

Tags: python, io, file-handling

i have this file that i am parsing with Python 2.7

```
a
b
```

that i parse this way:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
for l in f:
  if l == "a\n":
    break
# this causes an error
print f.readline()
```

this results in:

```
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
```

why does Python throw this error? i want to read a file up until a condition is met inside a loop and then read the result by calling `readline()`. don't see why there should be an error since the `readline()` call is outside the loop that references the file handle.

Comment: In python3 it works if you change print to print()

Comment: @MartinB i am using python 2.7

Comment: Because both operations manipulate the file's current position, and this can potentially lead to loss of data, as indicated by the error message. Python can't know that you're not going to use the iterator again after your `r.readline()` statement. Either read the file yourself and split it into lines, or use the `for line in f` iterator, but not both. For your case, you can simply do `print next(f)` at the end to advance the iterator instead of using `readline()`.

Comment: @LukasGraf: why is `next` different? both next and `for line in f` use an iterator no? i don't understand the difference

Comment: @lgd exactly, `next(iterator)` is just what the `for` loop is doing for you every iteration. So either use the iterator, *or* the `read() / readline()` methods, but don't mix them.

Answer (score 2):

You can get next line from file-iterator by calling `next()` explicitly.

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for l in f:
        if l == "a\n":
            break
    line_after_a = next(f)
    print line_after_a
```